# Keras implementation of LSTMCell (The class uses optional peep-hole connections, optional cell clipping, and an optional projection layer).

Tags: cell, keras, projection, lstm, clipping

According to my understanding, Keras LSTM cell is similar to Tensorflow

**BasicLSTMCell(RNNCell)**.
However, I am looking for the implementation of Tensorflow

**LSTMCell(RNNCell)**
in Keras (LSTMCell : The class uses optional peep-hole connections, optional cell clipping, and
an optional projection layer). https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py
https://research.google.com/pubs/archive/43905.pdf
Hasim Sak, Andrew Senior, and Francoise Beaufays.
"Long short-term memory recurrent neural network architectures for
large scale acoustic modeling." INTERSPEECH, 2014.

I am wondering without writing a custom layer, is there is any way to use this Tensorflow LSTMCell in Keras or is it already available?

Comment: Not really sure what the problem is here. Keras is just an API that makes using a backend NN software (tensorflow,theano) easier to access via python

Comment: I have the same question... because `import tf.keras` is too verbose.